# Can I set an iOS artwork for my <audio> element?

Tags: html, ios, audio, web, safari

I've googled a lot and read some Apple articles but couldn't find anything about this.

So I have an `<audio>` HTML element on my website that I can play on iOS devices. When I lock my phone and have the sound playing in the background, there is a default, gray artwork image on my lock screen. Is there any way I can change that? Like `<audio image="artwork.png">` or something? Feels like Apple would like to have that since an empty image doesn't look very clean...

Comment: I know that video elements have a poster attribute. But I don't know if iOS does anything special with that while the phone is locked. Maybe see if poster works with audio tags.